# How can I run both php and html code from MySQL?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a mysql table that stores php codes and html codes. Let's say this code is inside that table:

```
<html>
<head>
<title><?php echo $PageName; ?></title>
</head>
<body>
<?
echo $PageContent;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

what I want to do is to echo the variable's value and not the code itself.

I researched about this, then I found eval(); ,but unfortunately it only works on php codes so whenever I type html codes it will say unexpected '<' in line 1, this is because eval() doesn't recognize the html code. Can you give me a code that works for this?

Clarification: What I mean is that when I get the code from the database I want it to execute, not to echo the entire code. thanks

Comment: You want to store an entire PHP script in a MySQL database and execute it from there? I think you might be going about things the wrong way.

Comment: No what I mean is that when I get the code from the database I want it to execute, not  to echo the entire code.

Comment: What Mike W said makes me think he understood you perfectly. What you're asking to do just doesn't makes sense from a programming standpoint. I'm sure I could figure out a way to make it happen, but you'd be better off looking for an alternative. Perhaps if you could tell us more about how you're using this we could give you better direction.

Comment: It is all because I'm having a slow internet connection, and sometimes I'm kinda lazy to upload my codes to a ftp client app, so I made a solution, I created uploaded my codes on mysql to make updates on my codes fast.

Comment: Seriously: that's a really bad idea. It will make it impossible for your application to use a number of common PHP technologies, including class autoloading and opcode caching; and will make your code much less secure (as most SQL injection vulnerabilities can now be leveraged into remote code execution). There's a reason you don't see anyone else doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to do a **SELECT * FROM tbl_name**, they put everything into a **$mysql_fetch_assoc()** function.

Something like this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM website");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$row['page_title'];
$row['page_content'];
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to declare a tag in inline php every time its used

```
<?php echo $pagecontent; ?>
```

Comment: (also are you saving your documents as .php?  because it won't execute if you don't.)

Answer (score 0):

It seems very strange to me that you are saving PHP-Code in a MySQL Table. The usual setup would be:

- you have some PHP-Code and HTML-Code in a file with extension .php
- the PHP-Code reads structure data from a mysql-table, for example names of users
- the result is a complete html webpage that is sent to the client

a more advanced setup would be:

- you have some PHP-Code in a file with extension .php
- you have some HTML-Code in a template-file, it contians very little PHP
- the PHP-Code reads in the main file reads in the template,
- the PHP-Code in the main file reads structure data from a mysql-table
- the PHP-Code in the main file combines both, the result is a complete html webpage that is sent to the client